# First Tuesday of every Month

Tags: javascript

Hello I am trying to use the following code which is a mish mash of "lifted code" but it keeps pumping out todays date and time.

I am trying to get the date for the first Tuesday of every month at 19:00.

I am using W3C School Try-it for testing purposes.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function displayDate()
{

var myDate = new Date();
myDate.setHours(19, 00, 0, 0);
myDate.setYear(2013);

myDate.setDate(1);
myDate.setMonth();


//Find Tuesday
var tue = 2;

while(myDate.getDay() != tue) {
    myDate.setDate(myDate.getDate() + 1);

}

document.write(myDate);
</script>
</head>
<body>

<h1>My First JavaScript</h1>
<p id="demo">This is a paragraph.</p>

<button type="button" onclick="displayDate()">Display Date</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Roy

<==Update==>

I have use your code which works well but need to factor in  after the First Tuesday has happened for the next month, I have tried this if statement but breaks.

```
function getTuesday() {
    var datenow = new Date();
    var d = new Date(),
        month = d.getMonth(),
        tuedays= [];

    d.setDate(1);

    // Get the first Monday in the month
    while (d.getDay() !== 2) {
        d.setDate(d.getDate() + 1);
    }

    // Get all the other Tuesdays in the month
    while (d.getMonth() === month) {
        tuedays.push(new Date(d.setHours(17,00,00,00)));
        d.setDate(d.getDate() + 7);
    }
If (d.getDate() >= datenow.getDate)
{
    d.setMonth(d.getMonth() + 1);
    document.write(tuedays[1]);
}
Else
{
   document.write(tuedays[1]);
}


}
```

Comment: Which year ? all year ? Then it never end

Comment: it will be for every year. Its for a small website that hosts meetings on the first Tuesday of every month. So after the first Tuesday of the month has been it will update to the next months first Tuesday.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it's been over 8 years since I asked this question, and it showed up at the top result on Google for 'The first Tuesday of every month'. The original project is dead now, but I've gained more experience, I feel better placed to provide an answer.

First thing to note, is the original question wasn't obvious, and the title was just as ambiguous. The original goal, was to get the next occurrence of a first Tuesday of the month, so could be the current month, or next month depending on where you are in the month.

Because of the ambiguity in the question, I have tried to cover for those differences in interpretation in the answer.

My first function, is to get the occurrence of a specific day of the week for a given month and year. Thank you to @Amadan in the comments on one of the answers.

```
function GetFirstDayOfMonth(dayOfTheWeek, month, year){
    const date = new Date(year, month, 1);
    date.setDate(date.getDate() + ((7 + dayOfTheWeek) - date.getDay()) % 7)
    return date;
}
```

The next function, gets the next occurrence of a first specified day of the week given a date.

```
function GetFirstNextFirstDayOfTheWeek(currentDate, day){
    const returnValue = GetFirstDayOfMonth(day, currentDate.getMonth(), currentDate.getFullYear());

    if(returnValue.getDate() < currentDate.getDate()){
        return GetFirstNextFirstDayOfTheWeek(new Date(currentDate.getFullYear(), currentDate.getMonth() + 1), day);
    }

    return returnValue;
}
```

So to achieve the original question I can run the following example

```
const tuesday = 2;

function GetFirstNextFirstTuesday(){
    return GetFirstNextFirstDayOfTheWeek(new Date(), tuesday);
}
```

To achieve getting the first Tuesday of a Month

```
const tuesday = 2;

function GetFirstTuesday(month, year){
    return GetFirstDayOfMonth(tuesday, month, year);
}
```

And to finish getting all the first Tuesdays of a given year.

```
const tuesday = 2;

function GetFirstTuesdayOfEveryMonth(year){
    const dates = [];
    for (let index = 0; index < 12; index++) {
        dates.push(GetFirstDayOfMonth(tuesday, index, year));    
    }
    return dates;
}
```

```js
function GetFirstDayOfMonth(dayOfTheWeek, month, year){
    // Get the first day of the month
    const date = new Date(year, month, 1);
    // Set the date based on the day of the week. 
    date.setDate(date.getDate() + ((7 + dayOfTheWeek) - date.getDay()) % 7)
    return date;
}

function GetFirstNextFirstDayOfTheWeek(currentDate, day){
    const returnValue = GetFirstDayOfMonth(day, currentDate.getMonth(), currentDate.getFullYear());

    if(returnValue.getDate() < currentDate.getDate()){
        return GetFirstNextFirstDayOfTheWeek(new Date(currentDate.getFullYear(), currentDate.getMonth() + 1), day);
    }

    return returnValue;
}

const tuesday = 2;

function GetFirstTuesday(month, year){
    return GetFirstDayOfMonth(tuesday, month, year);
}

function GetFirstNextFirstTuesday(){
    return GetFirstNextFirstDayOfTheWeek(new Date(), tuesday);
}


function GetFirstTuesdayOfEveryMonth(year){
    const dates = [];
    for (let index = 0; index < 12; index++) {
        dates.push(GetFirstDayOfMonth(tuesday, index, year));    
    }
    return dates;
}



console.log(GetFirstNextFirstTuesday());
console.log(GetFirstTuesday(09, 2021));
console.log(GetFirstTuesdayOfEveryMonth(2022));
```

Hopefully, this can help anyone who may seem to stubble on this old post, and thank you to the people that did answer.

Answer (score 2):

Use below function, that will give you current month Tuesdays.

```
function getTuesday() {
    var d = new Date(),
        month = d.getMonth(),
        tuesdays= [];

    d.setDate(1);

    // Get the first Monday in the month
    while (d.getDay() !== 2) {
        d.setDate(d.getDate() + 1);
    }

    // Get all the other Tuesdays in the month
    while (d.getMonth() === month) {
        tuesdays.push(new Date(d.getTime()));
        d.setDate(d.getDate() + 7);
    }

    return tuesdays;
}
```

Comment: The first first loop could be replaced with non-iterative `d.setDate(d.getDate() + (9 - d.getDay()) % 7)` ;)

Answer (score 1):

I know that this is old but this is a function that i wrote based on what Sahal wrote that accepts a few additional features. Ill go through the arguments and returns below.

```
function getDates(dayString, month, year, first, allInYear) {
    if (!dayString) { console.error('Missing required parameter: dayString is required.'); return; }
    if (first === undefined || first === null) { first = false; }
    if (allInYear === undefined || allInYear === null) { allInYear = false; }
    if (year === undefined || year === null) { year = new Date().getFullYear(); }
    var converted = false;
    if (month === undefined || month === null) {
        var temp = new Date();
        if (temp.getDate() > 9) {
            month = ((temp.getMonth() + 1) == 12) ? 11 : (temp.getMonth() + 1);
        } else {
            month = temp.getMonth();
        }
        converted = true;
    }
    if (typeof month === "string" && isNaN(parseInt(month))) {
        month = month.toLowerCase().substring(0, 3);
        switch (month) {
            case "jan":
                month = 0;
                break;
            case "feb":
                month = 1;
                break;
            case "mar":
                month = 2;
                break;
            case "apr":
                month = 3;
                break;
            case "may":
                month = 4;
                break;
            case "jun":
                month = 5;
                break;
            case "jul":
                month = 6;
                break;
            case "aug":
                month = 7;
                break;
            case "sep":
                month = 8;
                break;
            case "oct":
                month = 9;
                break;
            case "nov":
                month = 10;
                break;
            case "dec":
                month = 11;
                break;
            default:
                var temp = new Date();
                if (temp.getDate() > 9) {
                    month = ((temp.getMonth() + 1) == 12) ? 11 : (temp.getMonth() + 1);
                } else {
                    month = temp.getMonth();
                }
                converted = true;
                break;
        }
    } else if (typeof month === "number" || (typeof month === "string" && !isNaN(parseInt(month)))) {
        month = (!converted) ? parseInt(month) - 1 : month;
    }
    if (typeof year === "string" && !isNaN(parseInt(year)) || typeof year === "number") {
        if (parseInt(year) / 1000 > 2) {
            year = parseInt(year);
        } else if (parseInt(year) / 10 >= 0 && parseInt(year) / 10 < 10) {
            var temp2 = new Date().getFullYear();
            year = (parseInt(Math.floor(temp2 / 100)) * 100) + parseInt(year);
        }
    } else if (typeof year === "string" && isNaN(parseInt(year))) {
        if (year === "this") {
            year = new Date().getFullYear();
        } else if (year === "last") {
            year = new Date().getFullYear() - 1;
        } else if (year === "next") {
            year = new Date().getFullYear() + 1;
        } else {
            console.warn('Year string not recognized, falling back to current year. (this, last, next).');
            year = new Date().getFullYear();
        }
    }
    var dates = [];
    //hang in there this is going to get a doosie
    var d = new Date(),
        dow = ["sun", "mon", "tue", "wed", "thu", "fri", "sat"],
        getDow = function(sd, dowa) {
            for (var i = 0; i < dowa.length; i++) {
                var day = dowa[i];
                if (sd.toLowerCase().substring(0, 3) == day) {
                    return i;
                }
            }
            return -1;
        },
        di = getDow(dayString, dow),
        getDIM = function(year, mon) {
            var isLeap = ((year % 4) == 0 && ((year % 100) != 0 || (year % 400) == 0));
            return [31, (isLeap ? 29 : 28), 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31][mon];
        };
    d.setFullYear(year);
    d.setMonth(month, 1);
    if (di == -1) { console.error('Range Error: Day of the week should be between sunday and saturday'); return; }
    if (first && !allInYear) {
        while (d.getDay() !== di) {
            d.setDate(d.getDate() + 1);
        }
        return d;
    } else if (first && allInYear) {
        var tm = 0;
        d.setMonth(tm, 1);
        for (var i = tm; i <= 11; i++) {
            while (d.getDay() !== di) {
                d.setDate(d.getDate() + 1);
            }
            dates.push(new Date(d));
            tm += 1;
            d.setMonth(tm, 1);
        }
        return dates;
    } else if (!first && !allInYear) {
        var eom = getDIM(d.getFullYear(), d.getMonth());
        for (var x = 1; x <= eom; x++) {
            if (d.getDay() === di) {
                dates.push(new Date(d));
            }
            d.setDate(d.getDate() + 1);
        }
        return dates;
    } else if (!first && allInYear) {
        var tm = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i <= 11; i++) {
            var eom = getDIM(d.getFullYear(), i),
                dim = [];
            d.setMonth(i, 1);
            for (var x = 1; x <= eom && d.getMonth() == i; x++) {
                if (d.getDay() === di) {
                    dim.push(new Date(d));
                }
                d.setDate(d.getDate() + 1);
            }
            dates.push(dim);
        }
        return dates;
    } else {
        return [];
    }
}
```

So the only required argument is the day string, optionally you can set month,year,first or all in a month and all in a year or not, month and year default to current, and first and allInYear default to false, But you can set first in moth, by passing null or undefined to the month and year parameter.

month parameter accepts: `null|undefined, number, or string eg 'July'`

year parameter accepts: `null|undefined, number 2 or 4 digit, string eg '19' or '2019' also 'last', 'this', 'next'`

returns Date object,Array[Date object...], or Array[Array[Date object...]...]

This has been tested and should cover most situations...